# Load separate sourcemap file in chrome dev tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

Is it possible to load an external source-map file (JSON), not included in the minified JS file used on a website?

So far the only ways I know of to include a source-map for a particular js file is to either inline it, add a link in comments or set the path in HTTP header.

So I wonder - is it possible to load a source-map file that can't be accessed via HTTP? For instance - load it from my local drive, and point it to the js file it is supposed to be mapping?

Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### August 2022, Chrome 104:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools
2. Go to "**Sources**" tab
3. Find the `.js` file you are looking for. Click on it.
4. Right click somewhere **ON THE SOURCE**.
5. Find "Add source map..." option there.

[image]

(I first wrote this [as a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34087143/load-separate-sourcemap-file-in-chrome-dev-tools/48706001?noredirect=1#comment127753013_48706001) to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48706001/2321594), but [@christian-vincenzo-traina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1850851/christian-vincenzo-traina) suggested having it as a separate answer.)

Answer (score 56):

I know question is old, but had it myself nevertheless. Here's how you do it in Chromium 63

[image: Add source map]

1. Open Debugger
2. Right-click in source code area
3. Select "Add source map…"
4. Enter URL to source map file

   - if browser is able to download it and process it then sources appear as entry in source tree.

PS built with hidden source (separate files, no source comment)

PPS does not matter where files are hosted, because it is URL. Must be accessible by browser.

Comment: I'm not seeing this option in Chrome 71 - has it been removed?

Comment: Maybe you could add a bullet list of steps, because it is not obvious what it going on. It is also not clear whether this is also just for sites running locally.

Comment: This also works with file based path, e.g. file:///C:/path/to/js.map.

Comment: @skeggse It only shows in non-formatted source code. You probably already have the :formatted version open.

Comment: @skeggse Had the same issue, fixed it by going into the dev tools Settings > Preferences > Sources and enabling Enable JavaScript source maps, then the Add source map... menu item appeared.

Comment: Same for me, it does nothing.  Tried loading relative URL, absolute URL, and even local path to the location of my code.  None of them do anything, none of them added any of my very valid files.

Comment: @skeggse I am on Chrome 101 and I found it. 1) You have to have "source maps" enabled in the settings.  2) You should right click on the code itself and find "Add source map".  For me it's in the middle of the 7 options, not the first one!

Comment: Can't find it in Chrome 103. Source map enabled in settings. When I right-click on the file I don't see that option.

Comment: You have to have the option set AND select the file on which you want to load the map for.

Comment: Thank you @Aidin, I think that can be a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

## January 2024

If you can't find **Add Source Map** option as [@Aidin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2321594/aidin)'s answer, You should enable it from:

**Dev Tools** > **Settings** > **Preference** > then **Check** the **Allow DevTools to load resources,...** option.

Comment: Did that, but Add Source Map options still didn't show up